# How do I find similar values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database with data in poor shape. I'm looking for a way to reduce the set of values in a column to the bare minimum, without throwing away information.

Example:

```
SELECT VALUE, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY VALUE;

VALUE     |COUNT(*)
FOO FOO   |50000
FOO.FOO   |40000
FOO DOO   |40
BAR BAR   |60000
BAR.BAR   |45000
BAR BAZ   |30
...
```

I'd like to find the query that can show me the groups towards which the data is converging (and help me make informed choices about `FOO FOO` <-> `FOO.FOO` and automate `FOO DOO` -> `FOO FOO` or `FOO.FOO`)

The database is Oracle 10g. I am aware of `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE` and `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER` functions, but I cannot wrap my head around using them in this case. The previous `GROUP BY` query should be under 10000 rows.

Comment: Do you know what algorithm you want to use? You know the domain of your data, we don't, so you know what changes can be made without throwing away information. In general, this sort of thing is exceedingly hard. If you want to say, for example, that you roll up any value that is 2 or fewer single character changes away from another value that occurs more frequently, you can do that. But then you'll have to specify the order in which rollups should occur if you want a deterministic result. And you'll have to decide whether rollups can cascade.

Comment: There are machine learning algorithms that allow a computer to try to create different "buckets" of similar values. Those are probably more robust than the simple algorithm I discuss above but also likely require a lot more work to implement and to understand how to set all the parameters appropriately. Any algorithm is likely to require some manual review of the results before you let the system start combining values automatically.

Comment: Looks like you need to create some intermediate data structures where you will link your descriptions to your keys. Once you satisfied, you can go ahead and populate your live table with unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is to define what is "similar". You need to specify a DETERMINISTIC way to say whether two strings are similar or not.

Think about creating a function `MyFanceAreSimilarFunction(string1,string2)` that you should fill. If you know how to check if they are similar, you will be able to code it :). Afterwards is just to add it to the where clause.

Also, have a look to [SOUNDEX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm)